# Octopus Tentacle on Load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, octopus-deploy

I am currently gathering some information for a blog on Octopus roles, envs and targets and have a question. While I was thinking of all the possible roles, I thought of a load balancer.

I have never seen a tentacle installed on the machine hosting an s/w load balancer. Is there anyone in this group who has seen such a scenario.

Pardon me if my question is silly but my knowledge of Load balancers is not great.

Thanks in advance.

Regards Tarun

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about a machine that runs a load balancer that would preclude putting a Tentacle on that machine. The only question is, what are you going to deploy to that machine hosting the load balancer?

New load balancer software might make sense. Or frameworks or other support software (.NET, node-js, whatever). But ordinarily you would *not* put web applications on this machine; the load balancing machine would not itself have the web applications that it load balances. (Of course you *could* run web apps on the same machine; the load balancer just needs to be told the URL to get to the app on its own machine. But it's not a usual configuration.)

And most other management tasks are easily accomplished with other tools like ansible, chocolatey, etc. So unless you're well invested in OctopusDeploy already, installing a tentacle on the load-balancing machine seems questionable.